# Understanding how the copying of the compressed Linux kernel works in head_64.S

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86

I am working on understanding how the Linux kernel v3.19 prepares for decompression on a machine with x86_64 architecture in `arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S`. The part that is confusing me is the copying of the compressed kernel image to another location in memory before decompression takes place. I have copied the code below with my understanding of each line; the lines with `// ?` comments are the ones I am having trouble with.

```
/*
 * Copy the compressed kernel to the end of our buffer
 * where decompression in place becomes safe.
 */
    pushq   %rsi  // %rsi contains the pointer to `boot_params`
    leaq    (_bss-8)(%rip), %rsi  // ?
    leaq    (_bss-8)(%rbx), %rdi  // ?
    movq    $_bss /* - $startup_32 */, %rcx  // ?
    shrq    $3, %rcx  // ?
    std           // set the direction so %rsi and %edi are decremented
    rep movsq     // copy data from %rsi to %rdi 8 bytes at a time
    cld           // clear the direction flag
    popq    %rsi  // restore pointer to `boot_params`
```

I know that at this point `%rbx` contains the location where the kernel will be relocated for decompression and that `%rbp` (while not mentioned in this code snippet) contains the location the kernel was loaded at runtime. Further, I am aware that `_bss` refers to the start of the `.bss` section as given by the linker script in `arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds.S`, and that the compressed kernel image that we want to copy is at `.rodata..compressed`, which sits between `.head.text` and `.text` (where we are currently, I believe).

What I am not following and need help with is:

1. What section does `_bss-8` refer to?
2. This may become clear once I understand what `_bss-8` is, but how does `(_bss-8)(%rip)` and `(_bss-8)(%rbx)` give us where the compressed kernel currently is and where it is going?
3. Why are we putting `$_bss >> 3` into `%rcx` as the counter for copying data? Why not something related to `rodata..compressed`?

Comment: The `shrq    $3, %rcx` on its own is trivial to answer: it turns a byte count into a qword count, for `rep movsq` instead of `rep movsb`.  (Because on most CPUs, `rep movs` backwards (with DF set) is not fast-strings optimized, so that would be about 8x slower.  Even in startup code, going 1 byte per clock cycle would suck.)

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes that much I understand - I was more referring to the fact that we are using something specifically `bss`-related as the counter which, as far as I understand it, does not relate to the size of the compressed kernel.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that part, but possibly it's copying a whole buffer regardless of how much is actually used?  I haven't really looked at any details here, but the copy size being exactly the compressed image size is only a likely assumption, not the only way it could work.

Comment: The minus 8 calculations compute the address of the last qword to be copied. Then `std` \ `rep movsq` moves something downwards (from high addresses to low). This probably means that the source and destination may overlap, and the source would be lower than the destination then. That's what a downwards repeated string movement is for.

Comment: The symbol bss marks the beginning of uninitialized data, so bss - 8 refers to the *last* qword of initialized data. This code copies everything between startup32 and bss.

Comment: @prl I sort of see that, but don't get how adding `_bss-8` to `%rip` makes sense. `_bss-8` refers to the last qword of uninitialized data, so adding `%rip` to that sends us way past it. No?

Comment: The form `symbol(%rip)` is a special case and the syntax is misleading. It doesn’t mean add symbol to rip, like you would think. It means to use an rip-relative reference to symbol. In an assembler like nasm, this would be written `[rel _bss-8]`.

Comment: Ah, I see! That is where all my confusion was. This chunk of code makes a great deal more sense now. Thanks for your help :)